# Probation Before Judgment

Tags: criminal-procedure, maryland

In a case that has the disposition Probation Before Judgement, what happens at the end of the probation period (assuming no violation of the probation)?  Does the defendant need to do anything (*i.e.* petition the court), or is the verdict entered automatically?

Interested specifically in the State of Maryland

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In a case that has the disposition Probation Before Judgement, what
> happens at the end of the probation period (assuming no violation of
> the probation)?

The case is closed and [the defendant does not have a criminal conviction associated with the charge](https://triallawyersmaryland.com/maryland-probation-before-judgment/). It is equivalent to what most states call a deferred prosecution.

> Does the defendant need to do anything (i.e. petition the court), or
> is the verdict entered automatically?

The guilty verdict is stricken with the probation before judgment is entered. After the duration of the probation before judgment has expired without a violation, there is no longer any basis for citing the defendant for a probation violation.

Comment: Your link does not work

Comment: @RonTrunk Thanks for catching that. Don't know what that happened. Fixed.